# how to make ticker in qgraphicsrectitem in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

how to make ticker in qgraphicsrectitem in Qt
i tried following

```
rect = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    text = new QGraphicsTextItem;

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    rect = scene->addRect(0,0,500,500);
    text->setPlainText("HELLO from constructor");
    scene->addItem(text);

    QFont font;
    fm = new QFontMetrics(font);
    ntextWidth = fm->width(text->toPlainText());
    text->setPos(0,rect->boundingRect().height()/2);
    ntextHeight = fm->height();
    QString strtxt = fm->elidedText(text->toPlainText(), Qt::ElideRight, ntextWidth-50, Qt::TextShowMnemonic);
    qDebug() << "Here Lenght in pixels:" << ntextWidth <<"====" <<ntextHeight <<"-----"<<strtxt.contains("…");

    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));
    timer.start(5);
}

GraphicsTicker::~GraphicsTicker()
{
    delete ui;
}

void GraphicsTicker::update()
{
    text->setPos(text->x()+1,text->y());
    if(text->x()==rect->boundingRect().width()-ntextWidth)
    {
        ntextWidth = ntextWidth-1;
        strNewText = fm->elidedText(text->toPlainText(),Qt::ElideRight,ntextWidth).remove("…");
        text->setPlainText(strNewText);
    }
    if(text->x() == rect->boundingRect().width()-20)
    {
        text->setPlainText("HELLO from constructor");
        ntextWidth = fm->width(text->toPlainText());
        text->setPos(0,text->y());
    }
```

I have used qgraphicstextitem and qgraphicsrectitem for this.
I moved the text depends on the position of rect using timer.
But it is not as perfect as Ticker
Please give me smart solution

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with ticker in Qt.
I have simply used Qlable and using this I rotated text on it and then I added this lable in Qgraphicsscene with Qgraphicsproxywidget.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you can make ticker by using Qpropertyanimation by simply adding Qlable into widget and set its start and end value so that it can look like a ticker is moving. For this "geometry" of label is consider for moving